# Need help finding largest value in a column in a JSON file (node.js)

Tags: node.js

I have an assignment in my computation for geophysicist course; the task is basically finding the largest value in a column of a txt file *(the value is the magnitude of the earthquake, and the file contains all earthquakes from 1990-2000)*. Then take the latitude and longitude of such earthquake(s) and plot it into a map.
The task is quite simple to do in python, but since I am devoting some free time to study webdev I am thinking of making a simple webapp that would do the complete task.

In other words, I would upload a file into it, and it would automatically appoint the biggest earthquakes into a google map.

But since I am kind of a noob in node.js I am having a hard time starting the project, so I am breaking it into parts, and I need help with the first part of it.

I am thinking of converting the `txt.file` with data into a `.csv` file and subsequently converting it into a `.json` file. I have absolutely no idea what algorithm I should use to scan the `.json` file and find the largest value of a given column.

Here is the first row of the original `.txt` file:

`1   5   0  7.0 274 102.000  -3.000`

here it is on a `.csv` file, using an online converter:

`1   5   0  7.0 274 102.000  -3.000`

And here it is on the `.json` file, again, using on a online converter:

`1\t 5\t 0\t7.0\t274\t102.000\t -3.000`

Basically I need to scan all the rows and find the largest value of the 5th column.

Any help on how I would start writing this code?

Thanks very much.

TLDR version:

Need to find the largest value of the 5th column in a JSON file with multiple rows.

Comment: what are the headers of your desired csv? You could make an object with keys equivalent to the csv headers and values as an array of values associated with that key _(header)_ .If you choose that route you could then just read each line of the `.txt` into this object using node [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)  library

Answer (score 1):

I had a go at this as a one-liner, code golf style. I'll leave out the usual "don't get Stack Overflow to do your homework for you" shtick. You're only cheating yourself, kids these days, yada yada.

Split, map, reduce.

```
let data = require('fs').readFileSync('renan/homework/geophysicist_data.txt')

let biggest = data.split('\n')
                  .map(line => line.split(/[ ]+/)[4])
                  .reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))
```

Having loaded up the `data` we process it in 3 steps.

1. **.split('\n')** By splitting on the newline character we break the text file down into an array, so that each line in the text file is converted into an item in the array.
2. **.map(line => line.split(/[ ]+/)[4])** 'map' takes this array of lines and runs a command on *every single line individually*. For each line we tell it that one-or-more spaces (`split(/[ ]+/)`) is the column separator, and once it's been broken into columns to take the fifth column in that line (We use `[4]` instead of `[5]` because javascript starts counting from 0).
3. **.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))** Now we have an array containing only the fifth column numbers, we can send the array directly to `Math.max` and let it do the hard work calculating our answer for us. Hooray!

If this data is even a little bit un-uniform it would be very easy to break this, but i'm assuming because it's a homework assignment that is not the case.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! That is great.
Just a followup question;- lets say that i want keep the other associated data to the largest magnitude, if i dont use the 'map' method would the var biggest be a 7-dimension array?
Then would i be able to sort this array by the largest value in a given column?
( probably with a custom sort function).

Comment: My idea is to plot the x first largest earthquakes into a google map.
But i need the long and lat associated with the largest magnitude to pass into the function.

Comment: That's more than a one liner I'm afraid. As a starting point, remove the `[4]` and the whole `.reduce()` line and then `console.log(biggest)`. This will print out the whole dataset in a way that's easy to work with in JavaScript. From there you'll need to feed this dataset into a `sort()`, a `slice()` and then into either a loop or into another `map()`. Come back and let me know if you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains just a lines with numbers with the same structure I'd not convert it to csv or json.

I'd simply go for parsing the `.txt` manually. Here is the code snippet how you could do this. I used 2 external modules: lodash (ultra-popular unility library for data manipulations) and validator (helps to validate strings):

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const _ = require('lodash');
const os = require('os');
const validator = require('validator');

const parseLine = function (line) {
 if (!line) {
  throw new Error('Line not passed');
 }

 //Splitting a line into tokens
 //Some of tokens are separated with double spaces
 //So using a regex here
 let tokens = line.split(/\s+/);

 //Data validation
 if (!(
   //I allowed more tokens per line that 7, but not less
   tokens && tokens.length >= 7
   //Also checking that strings contain numbers
   //So they will be parsed properly
   && validator.isDecimal(tokens[4])
   && validator.isDecimal(tokens[5])
   && validator.isDecimal(tokens[6])
  )) {
  throw new Error('Cannot parse a line');
 }

 //Parsing the values as they come as string
 return {
  magnitude: parseFloat(tokens[4]),
  latitude: parseFloat(tokens[5]),
  longitude: parseFloat(tokens[6])
 }
};

//I passed the encoding to readFile because if I would not
//data would be a buffer, so we'd have to call .toString('utf8') on it.
fs.readFile('./data.txt', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
 if (err) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  throw err;
 }

 //Splitting into lines with os.EOL
 //so our code work on Linux/Windows/Mac
 let lines = data.split(os.EOL);
 if (!(lines && lines.length)) {
  console.log('No lines found.');

  return;
 }

 //Simple lodash chain to parse all lines
 //and then find the one with max magnitude
 let earthquake = _(lines)
  .map(parseLine)
  .maxBy('magnitude');

 //Simply logging it here
 //You'll probably put it into a callback/promise
 //Or send as a response from here
 console.log(earthquake);
});
```

Comment: Thanks!
i will try this solution!!